# NameError: name 'Y' is not defined

Tags: python

Então, eu estou a tentar fazer uma calculadora muito simples, (um dos meus primeiros "projetos"). Nesta calculadora é necessário escolhes uma operação. Sendo que cada operação tem um número associado, e eu uso if e elif para que seja feita a escolha da operação. No entanto ao escolher a operação usando input, na hora da aplicação verificar os valores escolhidos, diz que a variavel neste caso y não foi definida. Edit: O problema foi resolvido mas agora aprceu outro no qual após escolher os números O programa não faz as contas e simplesmente acaba.

```
y = input('.:')

n1 = float(input("Primeiro Número "))
n2 = float(input("Segundo Número "))

if y == 1:
    print(n1, "+" ,n2, "=" (n1+n2))

if y == 2:
    print(n1, "-" ,n2, "=" (n1-n2))
elif y == 3:
    print(n1, "x" ,n2, "=" (n1*n2))
if Y == 4:
    print(n1, "/" ,n2, "=" (n1/n2))
calc()
```

Comment: No último if, o y está maiúsculo. O python é case sensitive, logo ele interpreta como uma nova variável, que ainda não foi definida.

Comment: Ah, faz sentido, obrigado pela ajuda, nao tinha reparado

Comment: Resolveu esse erro, mas agora há outro problema... Depois de escolher os números a aplicação não faz as contas, a app simplesmente acaba.

Comment: @Nuckhouse Provavelmente o programa acaba e a janela imediatamente fecha sem dar tempo de ver o resultado. Tente botar um `input()` no final, depois de todos os `y`.

Answer (score 1):

No último `if` sua variável é `Y` maiúsculo. Em Python, há diferenças entre letras maiúsculas e minusculas nos nomes de variáveis. Esse é o motivo de ele dizer que `Y` não existe - use`y`.

Outra coisa errada aí é que o retorno do `input` sempre é uma string - quando você pede os números que serão os operandos, você chama `float` no retorno do `input`, e isso vai converte-los em números: ok. Mas quando pergunta a operação desejada, você deixa como está, e nos `if` abaixo, compara o valor do input com números inteiros: o resultado será sempre `False`. Você deve ou converter o valor digitado para inteiro, chamando `int`, ou compara-lo com strings, colocando os valores a direito do `==` nos "if" entre aspas. (ex.:  `if y == "1":`)